# Python merge two *.doc files

Tags: python, merge, doc

I have to merge to *.doc files. I can't use python-docx because it did't support .doc. I tried to use olefile but i got this error:

> write_stream: data must be the same size as the existing stream

```
import olefile

ole = olefile.OleFileIO('asd1.doc')
data = ole.openstream('WordDocument').read()
ole1 = olefile.OleFileIO('asd.doc')
data1 = ole.openstream('WordDocument').read()
data2 = data1 + data
ole2 = olefile.OleFileIO('test.doc', write_mode=True)
ole2.write_stream('WordDocument', data2)
ole.close()
ole1.close()
ole2.close()
```

How to merge to *.doc files at linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

Pywin32 is used to merge two documents. 
The code for this would be similar to the one shown below:

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False

output = word.Documents.Add()

output.Application.Selection.Range.InsertFile('second.doc')
output.Application.Selection.Range.InsertBreak()
output.Application.Selection.Range.InsertFile('first.doc')

output.SaveAs('output.doc')
output.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can't use win32com because of linux machine.